# Need to override the redirect on cancel of a force:createRecord lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, salesforcedx, aura

Need to override the redirect on cancel of a force:createRecord lightning component.
I am doing this but this is not working for me.

```
({
    doInit: function (component, event, helper) {
        var LOOKUP = 'MRU_LIST&backgroundContext=%2Flightning%2Fo%2FContact%2Flist%3FfilterName%3DRecent'; 
        var createAcountContactEvent = $A.get("e.force:createRecord");
        createAcountContactEvent.setParams({
            "entityApiName": "Contact",
            "defaultFieldValues": {
                'Phone' : '415-240-6590',
                'FirstName' : 'Himanshu',
                'LastName' : 'Sharma',
                'Description' : 'Hello how are you..??',
            },
               "navigationLocation":"LOOKUP",
              "panelOnDestroyCallback": function(event) {
                window.location.href = "https://www.google.com";
            },
        });
        createAcountContactEvent.fire();
    }
})
```

Any help will be appreciated thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of using window.location.href to redirect have you tried using the force:navigate type of events?

Comment: yes i have tried.

Answer (score 0):

`panelOnDestroyCallback` is not working after `winter19` release [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000003VnmQAE) and moreover `panelOnDestroyCallback` is undocumented solution. i would suggest to use regurlar Apex controller for save the Sobject record and then in success of server call redirect to next page or previous by using  `lightning:navigation`  events see the [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:navigation/documentation) here

Comment: But i don't suppose to use custom buttons on my component.

Comment: you don't need to create custom button, in init function you can make Apex call for sobject record creation and then in success of server call you can navigate what ever you want. please update your Question with more details of your use case, so that it'll easy to give best solution.